# When spark streaming will execute the output operation on Dstream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was looking into the Spark Streaming programming Guide. I got one basic doubt like, when it will execute/compute the `Dstream` output operations.
For example(I got it from one example):

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7777) 
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    val connection = createNewConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    connection.close()
  }
}
// Start the computation
ssc.start()
// Wait for the computation to terminate
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Will it do the operation at each `batch-iterval` here 1 second. Or it wait till termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it do the operation at each batch-iterval here 1 second. Or it wait till termination.

It will read a batch at every 1 second interval and run the entire graph each time. In Spark terminology it's called executing a *job* at each interval.

The streaming job will only terminate once you single it to stop.

Comment: how can we terminate the stream. Is it via interrupting receiver thread?

Comment: Either by invoking the REST API, or killing the process.